# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for Application Loadbalancer in Elastic Beanstalk in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm using an ALB in my Elastic Beanstalk environment. It works (on 80 and 443) but I want to implement a redirect rule in the cloudformation template.

I was able to create the rule in the console:

```
If PATH is / Redirect to HTTPS://#{host}:443/app?#{query}
```

How can I do this for an ALB in Elastic Beanstalk in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 6):

You can add an EB extension that is a cloudformation snippet. It would look something like this:

```
albRedirect:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: redirect
        RedirectConfig:
          Protocol: HTTPS
          Host: '#{host}'
          Query: '#{query}'
          Path: '/#{path}'
          Port: '443'
          StatusCode: HTTP_301
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html

Comment: For some reason, `!Ref` on the LoadBalacnerArn did not work for me. I ended up using `LoadBalancerArn: Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer`

Comment: Also note that I had to disable the default listener (port 80) in order for this listener to be created.

`- Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:default
        OptionName: ListenerEnabled
        Value: False
`

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate on [Chris Pollard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983811/1286925).

After spending some energy on this, I ended up keeping the default listener on port 80, and attaching two listener rules. One for the HTTPS redirect, and one to allow healtchecks without the HTTP redirect. Notice the priority. Rules are evaluated in ascending priority order, starting with 1. The default rule of a Listener is evaluated last.

This allows me to enable HTTPS redirect on my Elastic Beanstalk load balancer while maintaining healtchecks on port 80 without the redirect.

```
Resources:
  ALBListenerRuleHealthcheck:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties: 
      Actions: 
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: 
            Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerTargetGroup
      Conditions: 
        - Field: path-pattern
          PathPatternConfig:
            Values:
              - /api/healthcheck
      ListenerArn: 
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener
      Priority: 1

  ALBListenerRuleRedirect:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties: 
      Actions: 
        - Type: redirect
          RedirectConfig:
            Protocol: "HTTPS"
            Host: "#{host}"
            Query: "#{query}"
            Path: "/#{path}"
            Port: 443
            StatusCode: "HTTP_301"
      Conditions: 
        - Field: path-pattern
          PathPatternConfig:
            Values:
              - /*
      ListenerArn: 
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener
      Priority: 2
```